# What are the correct command line comands for colmap to do structure from Motion reconstruction?

Tags: colmap

I have been able to do dense reconstruction using the COLMAP GUI.

However I am trying to do the same with the command line but could not achieve even Structure from motion reconstruction (much less dense)

What I want to do is very specific. I want to do

1. Feature extraction with camera model FULL_OPENCV, for all images with custom parameters and a camera mask. Also video frames and high definition

To do this I do

```
colmap feature_extractor \
  --database_path /working/project/database.db \
  --image_path /working/project/images/ \
  --ImageReader.single_camera 1 \
  --ImageReader.camera_model FULL_OPENCV \
  --ImageReader.camera_params 1850.0290000385532,1869.3040357074497,1918.181901686561,1520.8459429922048,2.0489745324154858>
  --ImageReader.mask_path /working/project/mask/ \
  --ImageReader.camera_mask_path /working/project/mask/center_camera_fov120.mask.png
```

Apparently it works.

2. Then I do the feature matching (that I want with overlap 10 and not quadratic overlap) with

   colmap sequential_matcher 
   --database_path $DATASET_PATH/database.db 
   --SiftMatching.guided_matching 1 
   --SequentialMatching.overlap 10

where `DATASET_PATH` is the path of the dataset

This also apparently work

3. But then I want to do a reconstruction with
   init_max_forward_mition 1.0 and init_min_tri_angle 2.0 and uncheck the refinements in camera parameters so I do

   colmap mapper 
   --database_path $DATASET_PATH/database.db 
   --image_path $DATASET_PATH/images 
   --output_path $DATASET_PATH/sparse 
   --Mapper.multiple_models 0 
   --Mapper.num_threads 6 
   --Mapper.ba_refine_focal_length 0 
   --Mapper.ba_refine_principal_point  0 
   --Mapper.ba_refine_extra_params  0 
   --Mapper.init_max_forward_motion 1.0 
   --Mapper.init_min_tri_angle 2

and then I get a lot of

```
Registering image #8 (3)
==============================================================================
I0206 11:18:05.436357   668 incremental_mapper.cc:495] => Image sees 917 / 6593 points
I0206 11:18:05.436779   668 incremental_mapper.cc:535] => Could not register, trying another image.
I0206 11:18:05.436784   668 misc.cc:198]
```

In the end I don't get the same results I got with the GUI

I suppose the last part is failing. How can I do a colmap mapper with the reconstruction options I wrote above?